# Java: Best OOP behaviour of Wgets controlling Drawings

Tags: java, oop, widget

I have implemented this Simple application showing different sorting algorithms in action.

[image]

However I am concern about the OOP design as I have one class for controls (at right) and another for the drawings (the gray panel). The problem I do not know how to communicate, for example, button click action between these two classes. What I did which it looks dirty and not OOP is passing necessary widgets as parameters to the Drawing class and then implement action listers there. Which does not seem to be right thing to do. would you please let me know what is the best thing practice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This question might be closed because you can get only subjective answers, but anyway...)

Your `Drawing` class is responsible for drawing the bars based on data provided to it. It does not have to know anything about the widgets (classes?) from the right of the screen. However, it needs to know what kind of data it can work with and must specify that somehow. In OOP, you use an interface to define that contract. In this case, you can have a `DrawingDataProvider` interface with a method `GetData` (which returns the data in a structure dictated by the `Drawing` class).

The controls on the right can then implement the `DrawingDataProvider` interface with the concrete `GetData` method returning the elements as they are being sorted (presumably by a third-party class that implements the algorithms) in the structure dictated by the interface. To put things together, you construct your `Drawing` class passing this implementation as a reference.